# using flat set wrapper around std::vector in constexpr context

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++, c++20, constexpr

I have a class FlatSet, which is a wrapper around std::vector and implements same interface as std::set.

Recently, new version of visual studio came out with support for c++20's constexpr vector, and I thought I could make the FlatSet constexpr too.

Incidentally, I also have a good use case: I have a pair of functions de/encodeAck, which takes integer and produces FlatSet based on its bits, or vice versa. I want to test these functions with static_assert.

Unfortunately, no compiler seems to accept it as of now (I tried msvc, clang and gcc - all trunk with c++20 enabled). Is my use case correct and the compilers are just not mature enough? Or do I misunderstand something?

Here is all the necessary code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // lower_bound, binary_search
#include <functional> // less


using uint8 =  std::uint8_t;
using uint16 = std::uint16_t;
using uint32 = std::uint32_t;
using uint64 = std::uint64_t;
using sint8 =  std::int8_t;
using sint16 = std::int16_t;
using sint32 = std::int32_t;
using sint64 = std::int64_t;
using uintPtr = std::conditional_t<sizeof(void*) == 8, uint64, uint32>;
using sintPtr = std::conditional_t<sizeof(void*) == 8, sint64, sint32>;


template<class Value, class Compare = std::less<Value>>
struct FlatSet
{
public:
    using key_type = Value;
    using value_type = Value;
    using const_iterator = typename std::vector<Value>::const_iterator;
    using const_reverse_iterator = typename std::vector<Value>::const_reverse_iterator;
    using size_type = typename std::vector<Value>::size_type;

    constexpr FlatSet() = default;
    constexpr FlatSet(const FlatSet &other) = default;
    constexpr FlatSet(FlatSet &&other) = default;
    
    template<class InputIt>
    constexpr FlatSet(InputIt first, InputIt last)
    {
        insert(first, last);
    }

    constexpr FlatSet(std::initializer_list<Value> init)
    {
        insert(init.begin(), init.end());
    }

    constexpr FlatSet &operator = (const FlatSet &other) = default;
    constexpr FlatSet &operator = (FlatSet &&other) = default;

    constexpr FlatSet &operator = (std::initializer_list<Value> ilist)
    {
        clear();
        insert(ilist.begin(), ilist.end());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr std::pair<const_iterator, bool> insert(const Value &value)
    {
        auto it = std::lower_bound<const_iterator, Value, Compare>(data_.begin(), data_.end(), value, Compare());
        if (it != data_.end() && equals(*it, value))
            return { it, false };
        return { data_.insert(it, value), true };
    }

    constexpr std::pair<const_iterator, bool> insert(Value &&value)
    {
        auto it = std::lower_bound<const_iterator, Value, Compare>(data_.begin(), data_.end(), value, Compare());
        if (it != data_.end() && equals(*it, value))
            return { it, false };
        return { data_.insert(it, std::move(value)), true };
    }

    template<class InputIt>
    constexpr void insert(InputIt first, InputIt last)
    {
        while (first != last)
            insert(*first++);
    }

    constexpr void insert(std::initializer_list<Value> ilist)
    {
        insert(ilist.begin(), ilist.end());
    }

    constexpr const_iterator erase(const_iterator pos)
    {
        return data_.erase(pos);
    }

    constexpr const_iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last)
    {
        return data_.erase(first, last);
    }

    constexpr uintPtr erase(const Value &value)
    {
        auto it = std::lower_bound<const_iterator, Value, Compare>(data_.begin(), data_.end(), value, Compare());
        if (it != data_.end() && equals(*it, value))
        {
            data_.erase(it);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    constexpr void clear()
    {
        data_.clear();
    }

    constexpr void reserve(uintPtr s)
    {
        data_.reserve(s);
    }

    constexpr const_iterator find(const Value &value) const
    {
        auto it = std::lower_bound<const_iterator, Value, Compare>(data_.begin(), data_.end(), value, Compare());
        if (it != data_.end() && equals(*it, value))
            return it;
        return data_.end();
    }

    constexpr uintPtr count(const Value &value) const
    {
        return std::binary_search<const_iterator, Value, Compare>(data_.begin(), data_.end(), value, Compare());
    }

    constexpr uintPtr size() const noexcept
    {
        return data_.size();
    }

    constexpr bool empty() const noexcept
    {
        return data_.empty();
    }

    constexpr const Value *data() const noexcept
    {
        return data_.data();
    }

    constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept
    {
        return data_.begin();
    }

    constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept
    {
        return data_.end();
    }

    constexpr const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept
    {
        return data_.rbegin();
    }

    constexpr const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept
    {
        return data_.rend();
    }

private:
    std::vector<Value> data_;

    static constexpr bool equals (const Value &a, const Value &b)
    {
        return !Compare()(a, b) && !Compare()(b, a);
    }

    friend constexpr bool operator == (const FlatSet &a, const FlatSet &b)
    {
        return a.data_ == b.data_;
    }
};



constexpr FlatSet<uint16> decodeAck(uint16 seqn, uint32 bits)
{
    FlatSet<uint16> result;
    result.reserve(32);
    for (uint16 i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        uint32 m = uint32(1) << i;
        if ((bits & m) == m)
        {
            uint16 s = seqn - i;
            result.insert(s);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

constexpr uint32 encodeAck(uint16 seqn, const FlatSet<uint16> &bits)
{
    uint32 result = 0;
    for (uint16 i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        uint16 s = seqn - i;
        if (bits.count(s))
        {
            uint32 m = uint32(1) << i;
            result |= m;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

static_assert(decodeAck(1000, encodeAck(1000, { 999 })) == FlatSet<uint16>({ 999 }));
static_assert(decodeAck(1000, encodeAck(1000, { 1000 })) == FlatSet<uint16>({ 1000 }));
//static_assert(decodeAck(1000, encodeAck(1000, { 1000, 999 })) == FlatSet<uint16>({ 1000, 999 }));
//static_assert(decodeAck(1000, encodeAck(1000, { 1000, 999, 990 })) == FlatSet<uint16>({ 1000, 999, 990 }));
static_assert(decodeAck(5, encodeAck(5, { 1, 65533 })) == FlatSet<uint16>({ 1, 65533 }));

// the commented lines issue this error:
<source>(213): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
C:/data/msvc/14.29.30130.2-Pre/include\vector(826): note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
C:/data/msvc/14.29.30130.2-Pre/include\vector(826): note: see usage of 'std::_Alloc_temporary<std::allocator<Value>>::_Alloc_temporary'
    with
    [
        Value=uint16
    ]
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xGeE6xcxP

Thanks

Comment: Seems worth calling attention to which static asserts produce errors and which don't. There's three that compile fine, and two that produce problems. Couldn't tell you why some work and some don't.

Comment: It's not implemented yet. `g++`'s `vector` doesn't have a `constexpr` destructor for example.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support says the latest MSVC should have constexpr support for vector, I agree with Nathan that maybe which ones are failing and which aren't may shed light?

Comment: I have updated the question to indicate which lines are causing errors

Comment: Do you really need that much code to demonstrate the issue?